# Print from SSIS script works when tested, but not when deployed

Tags: c#, sql-server, printing, ssis

When I run the package in Visual Studio the files print. When I deploy it and run it as a SQL Server job the files do not print. Any ideas? The package RUN AS is a domain admin account.

Here is the code.

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
   info.Verb = "PrintTo";
   info.Arguments = "\"printername\"";
   info.FileName = path;
   info.CreateNoWindow = true;
   info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = info;
   p.Start();

   p.WaitForInputIdle();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
   if (false == p.HasExited)
       p.Kill();
```

Comment: Have you tried making the window style something other than hidden to see if you get any errors?  Also set CreateNoWindow to false

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions and there was no error.

Comment: I assume that the print driver is installed on the server?